# Elasticsearch cluster with two nodes only

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, splitbrain

I have a two-node scale ES cluster. In the configuration of the ES, I set the `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` to **2**, and all the other settings are left to default (both nodes are master node, both nodes are data node, and both nodes are ingest).

In most of the blogs, I see that people come up with at least a three-node-cluster.
I have two question basically:

1. Do I need to worry about the split-brain issue with my two-node
   cluster?
2. How to configure the node related roles (master, data, ingest), when
   you have two nodes only?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-leader-election-in-general

Comment: If your master node will go down, then you wont be able to write, since to choose new master there should be at least 2 nodes

Comment: If performance is important then do one machine. ES is saying its better to have powerful machines than many machine. (Its in context that its better to have 3 nodes cluster than cluster with 10 machines)

Comment: And what if I create a strong node that does basically everything and a "secondary" node that is very weak from HW point of view, and basically does nothing just replicas the data for having backup for the hard days?

Comment: you simply can not configure a data node to only accept replicas (weak VM) or only hold primary shards (strong VM). If you add a second data node, all your shards will be distributed across all nodes available for shard allocation. so you´ll get a mix of primary and secondary shards on every data node. but what you can do is to tag a node as "strong" and a second as "weak". doing so, you'll be able to route specific indices to a particular node class based on said tags (see 'index.routing.allocation.require.box_type' setting)